# Unable to configure cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I am trying to use second level cache but I get an error.

Here is the `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="show-sql">true</property>
<property name="format-sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

<!-- second level cache -->
<property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">resource/ehcache.xml</property>
<!-- query level cache -->
<property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<mapping resource="/resource/student.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the error:

```
Feb 27, 2017 12:39:56 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.4.Final}
Feb 27, 2017 12:39:56 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 27, 2017 12:39:56 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at jspider.jogender.hiberTrial.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:19)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.EhcacheRegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.EhcacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:71)
    ... 11 more
```

I'm not sure what exactly is missing. What should be added more to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite specific. You have one exception caused by another, which is caused by yet another:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.cache.EhcacheRegionFactory] as strategy [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
```

It's telling you it can't find the name `org.hibernate.cache.EhcacheRegionFactory`. This should be `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`.

However, this error does not lie within the configuration file you included. Perhaps in `resource/ehcache.xml` ?